# mod_rewrite, RewriteMap, RewriteLock and threading

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, apache, mod-rewrite

I have RewriteMap configured to use an external application for rewriting the inbound URL. Works great. My concern now is threading and performance. Is there a way to have the external application process multiple request? We're using a RewriteLock now, so that only one thread at a time sends a request to the external application, but this seems like a performance bottleneck.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm upping your question, because *RewriteLock* was the answer to my question :-D Thanks!

Comment: It would have been nice if there's some kind of pooling support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this interesting dicussion with an apache developper: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3124928.htm

The bottleneck effect does not afraid them. If your mapping program is fast it should be ok. You could maybe test if this bottleneck effect exists.

The lock is used to prevent threaded requests to use the stdin of your prg in the same time. Seems difficult to change the way it works.

I have never used rewriteMap this way, I prefer using hash files with it. Is your internal redirect dynamic? If not you could make an hash file.

Comment: Yes, it's dynamic. It depends on a database lookup, and the database is constantly being updated, making it difficult to cache. The external app I have is pretty quick.

Comment: So you'll have to make tests, what's your traffic? with very high traffic you can parallelize this potential bottleneck by using several apache servers, with several physical or virtual servers and load balancers.

Comment: Probably have to go that route, but that negates all the reasons for using a multithreaded webserver like apache in the first place. Might have to just write our own module.

Comment: marked as an answer, feeling nice today. 8)   I'm using Siege to test the service, and performance seems ok so far.

Comment: you can use as well httpperf, and autobench on top of httpperf, to make real user sessions (or jmeter).